# Creating Databases In Run Time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application for monitoring the performance of an enterprise which i want to be used by multiple enterprises.My requirement is to create a new database for each user enterprise based on the database i have created initially . Can any body help me with some sql script or a link . I am using .net4 and c # , SQLSERVER 2008 . Thanks

Comment: What DMBS are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: What is the specific question? Give details on what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @shashi: `C#` and `4.0` in the tags mean nothing for your question. What database?

Comment: @Ken are you sure they don't?  I think he may be trying to spin up new DB instances from within C# using .NET 4.0?   (Granted, `4.0` is a useless tag, but `C#` may not be)

Comment: @Daniel: The OP is asking for an SQL script. How does C# or .NET 4.0 mean anything? Am I missing something? Does C#/.NET 4.0 include built-in support for any DBMS transparently (meaning any DB creation script will work on any DBMS without change)? This is a DB question, not a C# or .NET question, IMO at least.

Comment: @Ken - C#/.NET is relevant to this question. It means SMO is a possible option.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, you can right click your initial database, 'script database as' => 'create to' and save where you want. You can then use this script to deploy your database multiple times.